# Express js error when POST large arraybuffer

Tags: node.js, express

I use expressjs to upload large arraybuffer by POST and content-type is application/octet-stream.

I use middleware to read body content like that:

```js
const getRawBody = require('raw-body');
/**
 * Read body have content type is application/octet-stream
 */
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers['content-type'] === 'application/octet-stream') {
        // using rawbody to read arrray buffer
        getRawBody(req, {
            length: req.headers['content-length'],
            encoding: this.charset
        }, function (err, string) {
            if (err)
                return next(err)

            req.body = string
            next()
        })
    } 
    else {
        next()
    }

});
```

When arraybuffer have large file(> 50MB). It's cant not read the body and return error to client(Chrome crashed, firefox xhr return error).

I don't know why. Please help me resolve this problem.
Many Thanks

Comment: You're likely choking/running out of memory causing Chrome to crash. You'll need to stream the data instead of reading it entirely into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code snippet if it works.

app.use(express.bodyParser({limit: '100mb'}));